# Получить переменную из URL

Tags: jquery, url, click

На страницу можно попасть кликнув на одну из ссылок, в которых прописаны якоря. То есть при попадании на страницу её URL может иметь вот такой вид ../pavillions2.html#qwert

Вместо qwert может быть и другой id элемента, на который после загрузки страницы я хочу сделать клик: $('#' + urlId).trigger('click');

Как с помощью js или jquery можно получить из урла то, что после #?

Comment: вот тут есть об этом: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552944/how-to-get-the-anchor-from-the-url-using-jquery

Comment: Вообще якоря доступны из `document.anchors`. Если вы пытаетесь реализовать переход к блоку с определенным якорем после загрузки URL с хэшем, то, вроде как, это должно и без программных кликов из коробки работать, если необходимым блокам добавить ссылки  с `name="anchor_name"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строку url из адресной строки браузера в js можно получить вот так:

```
let href = document.location.href
```

Получить значение после последней решетки `#` можно разбив строку на массив и получить из него последний элемент:

```
let text = href.split('#').pop();
```

В урл сниппета нету `#` по этому возвращается просто урл, если будет решетка то все будет ок :)

```js
let txt = document.location.href.split('#').pop();
console.log(txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью функций с работы со стрингами

```js
let x = "pavillions2.html#qwert11111111111";
let z = x.substring(22);
document.write(z);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1) Используя объект `location` (Самый простой способ)

```js
let urlId = location.hash.slice(1)
```

Если хеша не будет существовать, то тогда вместо него будет пустая строка.

#### 2) Используя `match()` для конкретного документа (В некоторых ситуациях использовать лучше, чем первый вариант)

```js
let urlId = document.URL.match(/#.+/) ? document.URL.match(/#.+/)[0].slice(1) : ''
```

То же самое касается второго варианта, если хеша не будет существовать, то тогда вместо него будет пустая строка.